# Round or elongated toilet seat?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet, bathroom-fixtures

Not 100% sure if these are elongated or round seats. (I don't have physical access to verify.)

**Exhibit A**

[image: A]

**Exhibit B**

[image: B]

Comment: Without a way to actually measure them or compare them, I'm not sure we can provide an answer. They *look* round to me, but both pictures have obscured or cut off important parts.

Comment: There is just enough missing from the pictures to give a good answer..

Comment: That's why I'm asking. :-) (I didn't take the photos.)

Comment: I feel like this is a Captcha challenge: Choose all the toilets with round seats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are round. They are not interchangeable. Elongated seats go on elongated toilets and vice versa.

Comment: Sorry, i was not clear. All I have is these two pics, no physical access. Just wanted to be sure before I buy new seats.

Answer (score 1):

How long is the seat? Here's a guide:
http://www.pottytrainingconcepts.com/A-Round-Elongated-Seat.html

Comment: Sorry, i was not clear. All I have is these two pics, no physical access. Just wanted to be sure before I buy new seats.